# Trying to upload document in "Attachment" column of SharePoint list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to upload document in "Attachment" column of SharePoint list. I am able to upload the document but not view the document. The SharePoint list is given below image:-
[image]

When I am click on the "Attachment" column for view the document then not able to view the document. The error which is showing when I am click on that column is given in below image:-
[image]

Here I am using below code for upload the document in "Attachment" column :-

```
function Submitbtn(event) {
var listName = "AttachementTestList"
var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
var item = {
    "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
    "Title": $("#txtName").val(),
};

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var itemId = data.d.Id;
        var Path = $("#txtfile").val();
        var file = $("#txtfile").prop("files")[0];
        var uploadedfile = file.name;
        $.ajax
            ({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + itemId + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + uploadedfile + "')",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify
                    ({
                        __metadata:
                        {
                            type: "SP.Data.AttachementTestListListItem"
                        },
                        Path: Path,
                    }),
                headers:
                {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "POST"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Data Submitted Successfull");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error(xhr.responseJSON.error.message);
                }
            });
       
    },
    error: function (data) {

        console.log("not submitted");
    }
});
```

}

function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first, as a side note, I see you are using

```
_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl
```

to build your REST API URLs. I would highly recommend switching to use

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
```

because `siteAbsoluteUrl` is going to give you the absolute URL of the *root web in the Site Collection*, so if you happen to be working in a sub-site within the site collection, you are not going to be getting the correct URL. `webAbsoluteUrl` will give you the correct URL for whatever sub-site you happen to be in.

Now, I see that you are constructing the correct URL to use to upload an attachment.  If you have just created a new item there is a little shortcut you can take to get that URL, which I will show you.

The problem I'm seeing, though, is that to upload an attachment, you need to be sending an `ArrayBuffer` of the file as the `data` payload, not whatever object you are `stringify`-ing there in your second POST where you try to upload the attachment.  On JavaScript `File` objects, [there is a function `arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File#instance_methods) you can call to get the `ArrayBuffer` to send.

So here's how I would adjust your code:

```
// create the new item, but switch to webAbsoluteUrl
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // get the file
        var file = $("#txtfile").prop("files")[0];
        var uploadedFileName = file.name;

        // you can construct the upload URL the way that you were, this is fine
        var itemId = data.d.Id;
        var uploadUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + itemId + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + uploadedFileName + "')";

        // but, an alternate way to construct it would be
        var alternateUploadUrl = data.d.AttachmentFiles.__deferred.uri + "/add('" + uploadedFileName + "')";

        // now we need to get an array buffer of the file
        file.arrayBuffer().then(function (arrayBuffer) {
            $.ajax({
                url: uploadUrl,
                type: "POST",
                data: arrayBuffer,
                processData: false, // this is important to not have jQuery interfere
                headers: {
                    // when uploading attachments these are the 
                    // only two headers i have ever needed to include,
                    // and you probably want to remove the Content Type
                    // header because the content type you are sending
                    // is now an ArrayBuffer and not JSON
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Data Submitted Successfull");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error(xhr.responseJSON.error.message);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("not submitted");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you It is working for me